# Add Image using Image path in android

Tags: android

I want to save an image in my directory from select image gallery so I have problem to save dynamic image which is save I have select
so what solution for me

```
        Bitmap bitmap;
        OutputStream output;

        // Retrieve the image from the res folder
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.wallpaper);

        // Find the SD Card path
        File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        // Create a new folder in SD Card
        File dir = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath()
                + "/Attitude/");
        dir.mkdirs();

        // Create a name for the saved image
        File file = new File(dir, "myimage.png");

        // Show a toast message on successful save
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Saved to SD Card",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        try {

            output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // Compress into png format image from 0% - 100%
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, output);
            output.close();
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: What is the problem? Please put your Toast as last statement in the try block. (You are a little to early with your message now). Put another Toast in the catch block wich tells the user that things went wrong. Show in both Toast's the full path: `file.getAbsolutePath()'. Adapt your code here please. Tell us the full path.

Comment: Your question is not clear for me. Explain the question